# Running texture objects with streams

Tags: cuda, gpu

I am trying to use texture objects in streams. The elements in the buffers are allocated and all set to value 1:

```
float* aa[nStreams];
for (int i = 0; i < nStreams; ++i) {
        checkCuda(cudaMallocHost((void**)&aa[i], streamBytes)); // device 
         
        float* ar = aa[i]; 
        for (int k = 0; k < streamSize; k++) {
            ar[k]=1; 
        }
}
```

I then declare and create an array of textures in the loop over streams:

```
cudaTextureObject_t tex_ar[nStreams];

for (int i = 0; i < nStreams; ++i) {
    int offset = i * streamSize; 
      
    // create texture object
    cudaResourceDesc resDesc;
    memset(&resDesc, 0, sizeof(resDesc));
    resDesc.resType = cudaResourceTypeLinear;
    resDesc.res.linear.devPtr = aa[i];
    resDesc.res.linear.desc.f = cudaChannelFormatKindFloat;
    resDesc.res.linear.desc.x = 32; // bits per channel
    resDesc.res.linear.sizeInBytes = streamBytes;
        
    cudaTextureDesc texDesc;
    memset(&texDesc, 0, sizeof(texDesc));

    texDesc.readMode = cudaReadModeElementType;

    // create texture object: we only have to do this once!
    cudaCreateTextureObject(&tex_ar[i], &resDesc, &texDesc, NULL);
     
    checkCuda(cudaMemcpyAsync(&d_b[offset], &b[offset],
        streamBytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice,
        stream[i]));

    kernelTex << <streamSize / blockSize, blockSize, 0, stream[i] >> >(tex_ar[i], d_b, offset);

    checkCuda(cudaMemcpyAsync(&b[offset], &d_b[offset],
        streamBytes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost,
        stream[i]));
}
```

The kernel simply assign back the texture value:

```
__global__ void kernelTex(cudaTextureObject_t tex, float* b, int offset)
{
   int i = offset + threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x; 
   b[i] = tex1Dfetch<float>(tex, i);
}
```

So I expect, after kernels are finished, array b to have all its elements equal to 1. However other than the elements set by the first stream the rest of the elements are zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
b[i] = tex1Dfetch<float>(tex, i);
```

should be this:

```
b[i] = tex1Dfetch<float>(tex, i-offset);
```

Each of the textures you are passing is of size `streamSize`.  So you are texturing beyond the end of the texture, for iterations after the first.  Yes, it is legal to [texture beyond the end of the texture](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#texture-memory).  It appears that the return value is zero in this case.

Note that when the resource type is linear, [the address mode is ignored](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__TEXTURE__OBJECT.html#group__CUDART__TEXTURE__OBJECT_1g16ac75814780c3a16e4c63869feb9ad3). Therefore you don't have any control over the out-of-range behavior.   Again, I assume in this case the out-of-range behavior is to return 0.

Comment: with streams we use cudaMemcpyAsync for copying the global memory and pass the stream[i] along with the offset index of the buffer for stream[i]. Is there a similar way to do with texture objects? As to have one texture(instead of an array of textures like in my example) and to create/copy it asynchronously? I have used an array of textures in my example, is this a correct practice in working with textures in streams?

Comment: array of textures should be fine. You should also be able to create a single texture (object) and use it in a similar fashion - with offsets.

Comment: I don't understand the reason for having 2 memset call after cudaResourceDesc and cudaTextureDesc. If memsets are commented or the second argument is any number other than zero, the program throws exception. Could you shed some light on this plz.

Comment: They are used to initialize all elements of the structures to zero.  If you don't do that, elements of the structure may have random values, and you will generally get errors based on that. You can see the structure definitions at the link I already included in my answer [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__TEXTURE__OBJECT.html#group__CUDART__TEXTURE__OBJECT_1g16ac75814780c3a16e4c63869feb9ad3).  For example the `cudaTextureDesc` structure has various elements besides the one you set (to `cudaReadModeElementType`).  The memset sets all elements to zero.